# Shoud I use 60GB heap size?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, heap-memory

I am wondering setting heap size to more than 32GB will increase performance or not?
I have a server with 128GB memory.

As I read, if I increase it to 48GB, the performance will decrease, but what about setting it to 60GB?

Comment: There's no single correct answer to that, as it depends on your program and what it does.

Comment: Instead of wondering, you can test it and see.

Comment: If you need it yes, if you don't no. In short: some applications benefit from additional heap memory, others actually benefit from the memory being available to the OS (i.e. don't assign as much heap). 32GB is a threshold because below that value JVMs can use 32bit pointers internally even on 64bit machines, which saves memory and require fewer memory accesses. In the end the correct answer depends a lot on which application(s) you're running, what the workload is and many other parameters.

Comment: I want to set it for elasticsearch, I had set it to 60GB and elastic is using all of it. So I am wondering setting it to 32GB may help or not.

Comment: You can set the memory to 128 mb, then do some stress loading and profiling. Profiling will show you how much memory you application really use. Usually performance (average response time) degrades because garbage collector spending to much CPU time with cleaning garbage ( it means - not enough memory). I.e. in most cases 60GB will make performance better. In any case it could be to expensive since your app need just 6, which means you can utilize your 128 G server more cost effective.

Answer (score 1):

No, you shouldn't, increasing your heap size for values higher than 30GB won't increase performance, it will probably make things worse.

Elastic [recommends](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/heap-size.html) to use a maximum value between 26 GB and 30 GB, depending on your system.

If you are having performance issues you first have to identify if those issues are related to your heap size or not, it could be a disk i/o issue.

You could also spin up another instance on the same machine to increase your cluster.

Comment: I think Elastic is just another java app and documents of EL seems to say that, so changing the heap size should have same effect like other app. Tell me if I am wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Basically heap memory depends on your application. What kind of process doing in the application.For the normal applications we starts allocating memory from the 30 % of the total memory.if we have exceptions like Out of Heap Memory then increase it according to requirement.Maximum Heap size we can allocate to application only to 60% of the total memory.This is the best practice that normally followed.